# Which package do I have to import for Play Framework Filters

Tags: java, playframework

Which packages do I have to import to get this code from playframework docu get run.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import akka.stream.Materializer;
import play.mvc.*;
    
public class GlobalHeaders extends Filter {

    @Inject
    public GlobalHeaders(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> nextFilter,Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {

        return nextFilter.apply(requestHeader).thenApply(result -> {
            return result.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .setHeader("Allow", "*")
                    .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
                    .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent");
        });
    }
}
```

Error is that the extends Filter says cannot find Symbol Filter

[image]

build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc ,  cache , javaWs, filters)

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.4.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "filters-helpers_2.11" % "2.4.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.0"

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )  

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it must be a filter from the `mvc` package:

```
import play.mvc.Filter;
```

Your code has `import play.mvc.*;`, so

> Error is that the extends Filter sais cannot find Symbol Filter

must not be present.

**Fix**

You need to change `setHeader` to `withHeader`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import akka.stream.Materializer;
import play.mvc.*;


public class GlobalHeaders extends Filter {

    @Inject
    public GlobalHeaders(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> nextFilter,Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {

        return nextFilter.apply(requestHeader).thenApply(result -> {
            return result.withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .withHeader("Allow", "*")
                    .withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
                    .withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent");
        });
    }
}
```

**Library Fix**

If you use Play as 3rd party library, then you need to add filters as dependency, for example:

Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/filters-helpers_2.11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>filters-helpers_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.14</version>
</dependency>
```

SBT:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/filters-helpers_2.11
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "filters-helpers_2.11" % "2.5.14"
```

**Standart installation**

If you use standard play installation do not include `filters` into `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt`. Play already has it, so adding it one more time will do a conflict.

Play documentation does not say to add filters as a dependency:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters

Comment: How do you use Play? is it a standard installation? It looks like you use it as library, then you need to add filters as dependency

Comment: Your installation is standard - remove `filter` from the `libraryDependencies`

Comment: dosn't work. cant resolve filter. added my sbt above

Comment: remove `libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "filters-helpers_2.11" % "2.4.2"` and change `libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc ,  cache , javaWs, filters)` to `libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc ,  cache , javaWs)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142056/discussion-between-felix-and-andriy-kuba).